# How can I persist 2d string arrays into a sql database?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database-design

I made a program some years ago in Java to manage a laboratory. The main goal was to have quick access to people data. Every person added to the system had a name, an id, and two "2 dimensional string arrays String[][]" of 4 columns and 6 rows each.

Each column is a formula of that person. So a person has a maximum of 8 formulas of six strings each.

These objects are controlled by an arraylist in an object that has more functionality (the System class),  like searching inside that array, updating removing etc...

The technique I'm using for storing the system class and the objects arraylist is serializing the data into a file. Every time there is a change in an object the whole system class goes serialized. It is totally inefficient now because there are like 3000 persons in it. The file is about 2 MB.

I need to get rid of these way of saving the data, I was thinking of using a database, for better searching and let other clients access the same data.
The problem I'm facing is how to save the two 2d arrays of strings for each person. Should I create an array of 8 strings and have each array concatenated representing a column? Should I create 2 extra tables at the database for a many to many relationship?

Thanks.

*BTW; I'm planning to use JavaFX for making the new version of the program.*

---

Here is the class I want to persist.

```
package ingresodefichas;

import java.io.*;

public class Ficha implements Serializable {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String apellido2;

    private int id;


    private String tabla1[][];
    private String tabla2[][];

    public Ficha() {
        this.setNombre("sin nombre");
        this.setApellido("sin Apellido");
        this.setTabla1(new String[6][4]);
        this.setTabla2(new String[6][4]);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
        public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getApellido2() {
        return apellido2;
    }

    public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
        this.apellido2 = apellido2;
    }


    public String[][] getTabla1() {
        return tabla1;
    }

    public void setTabla1(String[][] tabla1) {
        this.tabla1 = tabla1;
    }

    public String[][] getTabla2() {
        return tabla2;
    }

    public void setTabla2(String[][] tabla2) {
        this.tabla2 = tabla2;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.getId() + " - " + this.getNombre() + " " + this.getApellido() + " " + this.getApellido2();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just to let you know people what I did to resolve this.
I created 2 strings for each person in the system each string contains the json representation of the arraylis. 
I used the Gson libraries from google.
It saved me a lot of time. 
Also used a MySQL  server. 
And JavaFX as the GUI.
thanks @ankhzet,

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I followed your advice too  about the GSON libs.
thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked for you =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each string in that `String[][]` table is unique, than separating that data into another table has no benefits, normalization attempt will only result in additional unwanted logic, like fetch strings by relations and make sure, that related strings will be removed on person removal.

In order to save entire tables to database column, you can just serialize/unserialize them (string tables) as usual.

If you provide question with example of, like, two person's serialized string tables with formulas, then SO community will be able to give the answer that is more suitable to situation.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You mean serialize the 2darrays? into a blob?

Comment: `blob`, `varchar`, `text`... Not a big difference (at least, `text` allows you to preview column data in any database client... if it needed, anyway).

Comment: The easiest thing is probably to serialize the array to JSON, using GSon, and store it in t a text column,

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek, from `The technique I'm using for storing the system class and the objects arraylist is serializing the data into a file` it looks like @HoNgOuRu already using some serialization/unserialization algorithm. Depending on that array contentc, that can be simple concatenation with some `glue` delimiter %)

Comment: Thank you for your opinions. I'll stick with @GreuBeardedGeek 's idea of passing the data using JSON. I believe it is better than serializing it from the point of view of portability.
Thank you again, I'll mark this as answered.